# PHP Functions declaration increasing memory usage

Tags: php, function, optimization, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to optimize memory usage in my PHP application, so I started placing `memory_get_usage` function at specific places like after `includes`, arrays declarations, etc. So I can see where the memory peak starts.
By doing this I found out that the memory used tripled after including a `functions.php` file which only has functions declarations (no executions or classes there), just the classic:

```
function myFunction(){
//some code
}
```

Searching the web didn't really help much, I could not find much information about memory usage on function declarations.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You program needs to be stored somewhere in memory before running. So it is an expected behaviour to see memory usage rises after loading `functions.php`. This is not a "memory leak". This is a legitimate use of memory. The problem of your application might be to store and load too many functions in `functions.php`.

Comment: Are you talking about Wordpress? Or are you talking about some custom PHP application you bake up from scratch?

Comment: Its a custom application, it uses like 2MB of memory just by loading that file which isn't huge btw.

Comment: You don't need all the functions on every request / response of your application, right? Why not breaking the `functions.php` down and only load the relevant functions at the time of use?

Comment: Also, does it only contain function declarations? Or does it have other side effect (e.g. loading database)?